# Http Header Base Authentication Providers

Tags: authentication, siteminder

What open source products are there, that are comparable or similar to CA SiteMinder, that can provide secure HTTP Header based integration for Web Applications?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question. Not really sure what you are looking for.

Comment: In simple, I am looking for an open source alternative for Siteminder.

Answer (score 0):

Found OpenAm has some relevant features to Siteminder.